# Create alertview and get the label tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to create a custom alertview class but I am having problems creating a completion block for the view tapped

What I want is something like this,

```
+ (void)alertview:(UIViewController*)vc handler:(void (^)(UITapGestureRecognizer *))callback{
    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    lbl1.text = @"A";
    UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    lbl1.text = @"B";
    UILabel *lbl3 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    lbl1.text = @"C";
}
```

and when the user touches, for example, lbl2

```
[RFAlertView alertview:self handler:^(UITapGestureRecognizer *selected){
                    NSLog(@"selected label is : %@",selected);
                }];
```

Comment: You have no object for `UITapGestureRecognizer ` in the alert method./

Comment: it's not an alert, is a custom view with more labels

Comment: selected.view.title

Comment: Can you describe your work flow. And add your expected UI and developed UI so that we can understand your question more perfectly.

Comment: `UIAlertView` is deprecated, you should be using `UIAlertViewController` instead.

Comment: What is `RFAlertView`?

Comment: have you added an event to the label? you need to create a `UITapGestureRecognizer ` and associate it to the label you want

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your `UILable` have `UserIneteractionEnabled` is set to `YES`